# dynamically create facebook share metatags [og:] in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, google-plus

I am trying to create meta tags in code behind for my website which has a blog section. so each blog will have their own title, image. hence created in code behind. just wanted to make sure if this is right and Facebook/Google+ will recognize it.

## CODE BEHIND

```
private void AddMetaTagsForPage(object tempObject)
      {
            string[] metaTags = {"og:title", "og:site_name", "og:type", "og:url", "og:image"};

            foreach(string str in metaTags)
            {
                  HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();

                  switch(str)
                  {
                        case "og:title":
                              tag.Name = str;
                              tag.Content = tempObject.ChallengeTitle;
                              Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
                              break;
                        case "og:site_name":
                              tag.Name = str;
                              tag.Content = "http://www.mysite.com";
                              Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
                              break;
                        case "og:type":
                              tag.Name = str;
                              tag.Content = "blog";
                              Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
                              break;
                        case "og:url":
                              tag.Name = str;
                              tag.Content = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                              Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
                              break;
                        case "og:image":
                              tag.Name = str;
                              tag.Content = String.Format("http://static.mountainwarehouse.com" + tempObject.ChallengeImageURL);
                              Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
                              break;
                  }
            }
      }
```

## GENERATED HTML

```
    <meta content="No appointment necessary. We hear you coming." name="og:title">
    <meta content="http://www.mysite.com" name="og:site_name">
    <meta content="blog" name="og:type">
    <meta content="http://dev.mysite.com/entries/viewentry.aspx?entryId=34"
    name="og:url">
    <meta content="http://static.mysite.com/Images/2a7803a2-e8f1-424c-9f53-3ddc1fe33c3e.jpg" name="og:image">
```

on facebook and google+ it says that you must have meta tags in this format.

```
<meta content="No appointment necessary. We hear you coming." property="og:title">
```

instead of property keywords i have name. I dont know how to create that in asp.net. is it valid for facebook?

please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All your meta tags in the code behind are missing the part where you set the property attribute. Something like

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");
tag.Content = "Title";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

See the following thread,
[How to send the og:Title og:Image og:Description og:url info from C# to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946177/how-to-send-the-ogtitle-ogimage-ogdescription-ogurl-info-from-c-sharp-to-fac)

Answer (score 1):

For Google+, schema.org microdata is preferred over Open Graph tags. You can decorate any HTML tags with schema.org microdata and can use the [Google+ snippet tool](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) to generate example content. In your case, you could just add an itemscope to the HTML tag such as:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<head>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Blog title">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="A blog post description">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="http://example.com/test.jpg">
</head>
<body>
  ...
```

In your case, all you need to do to improve the result for Google+ is add the itemprop tags to your code, for example:

```
case "og:site_name":
  tag.Name = str;
  tag.Attributes.Add("itemprop", "name");
  tag.Content = "http://www.mysite.com";
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
  break;
```